# How do I get all the nodes from a TinyMCE selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I want to get all the nodes of a selection with tinymce so I can later work with each node.

I tried getSel(), but it seems to be a range, not the nodes themselves, anyway, I'm looking for something like obtaining an array of the nodes of a selection.